# Substituting values in a text field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a text field in one of my table as

```
##EmploymentStatus## = 'TERMINATED W/ BENEFITS' and
##UserDefinedField5## = null or ##UserDefinedField5## = 'N' or ##UserDefinedField5## ='NO'
```

Above is the user input and I need to convert it to SQL query
I want to remove the  ## ## and insert my column name into it.

I have tried using stuff function but it only works for the first field i.e. EmploymentStatus but i need this to be done for entire field.

Please suggest.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, show the results you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Result should look like following:-

eed_employment_status= 'TERMINATED W/ BENEFITS' and
eed_user_def_5 = null or eed_user_def_5 = 'N' or eed_user_def_5 ='NO'

These are basically the db fields.

Comment: Also provide the code that you're using.  It's not enough to just say "I tried using the STUFF function" - you need to post the exact call, including the parameters you used.

Comment: Aside: be sure to parenthesize things explicitly if you have a query that uses both `AND` and `OR`, otherwise the results are almost certainly not what you want. Also, take care that nobody is motivated to make the query `; UPDATE employees SET salary += 10000 WHERE name='Evil' --`, or else take all precautions against such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Replace(col, '##', 'eed_') 
FROM   (SELECT Substring(col, 1, Charindex('#', col, 3) - 1) AS col 
        FROM   tab)rep
```

Comment: That's the right direction, but you'll need to be more specific than just changing "##" to "eed_".

Comment: Edited it. Kindly check

Comment: That's still not going to do what the original poster says that he needs.  The issue isn't in the "From" clause - it's in the REPLACE function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @dATA AS TABLE (data nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO @dATA
SELECT '##EmploymentStatus## = ''TERMINATED W/ BENEFITS'' and ##UserDefinedField5## = null or ##UserDefinedField5## = ''N'' or ##UserDefinedField5## = ''NO'''

SELECT data,REPLACE(REPLACE(data,'## =',' = '),'##','eed_') AS Result
FROM @dATA
```

Demo result :http://rextester.com/FKGO70085